# have access to a variable after callback is called

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is an existing API that I'd rather not change that gets the connection to a database.  The signature looks like

```
getDBConnection(function(error, DBConnection) {
   // do biz logic
});
```

There is another variable that I want to use within getDBConnection

```
exports.doSomething = function(foo) {
    getDBConnection(function(error, DBConnection) {
        logger.info(foo);
    });
};
```

But foo is undefined in the getDBConnection callback.  Is there somethign I can do to have access to Foo within getDBConnection?

Comment: That depends on what the value comes from.  It sounds like you need more callbacks.

Comment: If `foo` has a value and is not shadowed, you will be able to access it in the callback function. Please provide a piece of code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo` is still in scope, but perhaps it is getting overwritten by some other code before your callback is being invoked. You can explicitly create a new `foo` scoped only for your callback with an IIFE:

```
var foo;
getDBConnection((function(foo) {
    return function(error, DBConnection) {
        // foo = whatever it was
    }
})(foo));
```